# Problemas ao scanear strings dentro do comando switch (C)

Tags: c, string, switch

Estou tentando fazer um programa que codifica e decodifica strings que são dadas pelo usuário pelo método da cifra de césar, usando switch-case para a selecionar o que deve ser feito, porém ao tentar ler uma string dentro do case (somente dentro do case isso ocorre) o programa ignora o scanf e vai direto para a linha seguinte. Eu já tentei tudo o que sabia e nada deu certo, qualquer ajuda seria bem vinda.
As strings texto e mensagem ambas são de tamanho 50, alf é uma string que contém o alfabeto, chave é um int que é o numero de casas que são avançadas na mensagem dada.
Meu código está deste jeito:

```
        case 1:
        printf("Digite sua Mensagem\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]s",texto);
        strcpy(mensagem,texto);
        printf("Digite a Chave de Codificação\n");
        scanf("%d",&chave);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(texto);i++) //loop p/ cada caractere da mensagem inicial
            for(j=0;j<strlen(alf);j++){ //loop p/ cada caractere da mensagem inicial
                if(texto[i]==alf[j]){
                    mensagem[i]=alf[j+chave];
                    break;
                }else if(texto[i]==toupper(alf[j])){
                    mensagem[i]=toupper(alf[j+chave]);
                    break;
                }else if(isspace(texto[i]))
                    break;
            }
        system("cls");
        printf("A Mensagem Encriptada É:\n");
        printf("%s\n",mensagem);
        system("pause");
    break;
```

Comment: Você tem certeza de que o buffer de entrada está realmente vazio? Não sobrou nenhum '\n' de alguma leitura anterior lá?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, como há apenas 1 case no código apresentado, não posso sugerir que considere trabalhar com outros operadores condicionais (if-elseifs-else).

Enfim, o problema parece estar relacionado ao "scanf" e "\n".
Apesar de ser um "chute" que estou dando, pode funcionar, pois esses dois elementos costumam ser o motivo pricipal de vários problemas.

O que acontece, é que *scanf* não se comporta exatamente da forma que nos é aparente. Essa função "lê" de um canal de entrada "bufferizado", chamado *stdin*. Por "bufferizado", entende-se que esse canal não deixa seu programa "scanear" enquanto uma nova linha for lida, ou seja, enquanto o usúario não pressionar "Enter". No entanto, a familia de funções *scanf* não olha por novas linhas (não verifica), e trata o o caractere de nova-linha como um caractere normal. O que pode estar acontecendo, é que o *scanf* pode estar lendo apenas o *\n*, e por isso aparenta que a função (*scanf*) não é chamada.

Sugiro que use *fgets* para ler uma linha inteira da entrada padrão e então analisar tal linha com *sscanf*. Com isso, se livra do problema da entrada aparentar estar "não-sincronizada" e também permite que "scaneie" uma linha várias vezes, apesar de usar sintaxes de entrada alternativas.

Então, vou passar uma versão "exemplo", ao invés de copiar todo o seu código, pois assim vou poder explicitar os *#includes* e variáveis criadas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

char *texto_constant;
char texto_buf[100];
int whatever[100], i; /* No caso não há necessidade desse array                                        
                         mas deixarei como exemplo adicional */

printf("Introduza um inteiro: ");
fgets(whatever, 100, stdin);
sscanf(whatever, "%d", &i);

switch (i)
{
   case 1:
    printf("Digite sua Mensagem");
    fgets(texto_buf, 100, stdin);
    sscanf(texto_buf, "%100s", texto_constant); /* Aqui, até onde sei é  
                                                necessário explicitar o                                                                                             
                                                No. de chars. Caso contrário, me corrijam por favor. */
    strcpy(mensagem, texto_constant);
          .
          .
          .
}
}
```